# jQuery Masonry not working in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get even the slightest bit of Masonry to work. I am mind-boggled! Here is the code:

```
<LINK rel="Stylesheet" href="App_Themes/Theme1/Style.css"  type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.masonry.min.js" />
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-transitions.js" />
<script src="Scripts/box-maker.js" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $container = $('#container');
        $('#mini-container').masonry({
            columnWidth: 20
        });
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.w1',
            columnWidth: 120,
            isAnimated: true,
            gutterWidth: 2,

            animationOptions: {
                durantion: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });

        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.mini',
            columnWidth: 120
        });

        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.myImages',
            columnWidth: 120,
            isAnimated: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is just a snippet of the html so you can see the div ids and classes - but nothing takes effect.

```
     <div id="container">
    <div class="mini">
    <p class="w1 h1">Lorem etc.... you know the text</p>
     <div class="myImages">
     <img id="image1" src="Images/green1.jpg" />
     </div>
 <p class="w1 h1">Lorem etc.... you know the text</p>
    <div class="myImages">
     <img id="Img1" src="Images/Marcia_02.jpg" />
     </div>
     <p class="w1 h1">Lorem etc.... you know the text </p>
</div>
```

I cut out a lot of the text so you can just see that tag names. And the files are in the  correct locations according to my JavaScript source.  But nothing happens - what's wrong here?

Comment: Put together a demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar, and reproduce the problem so we can see what's happening, or not. Incidentally, `script` tags are *not* self-closing void, or empty, elements.

Comment: Maybe its your self closing script tags

Comment: Thank You!!  I get so used to .net that sometimes I forget things like this.  Thank you!!!   I changed the self-enclosing javascript tags and the page totally changed.  Of course it looks nothing like jquery masonry that I was aiming for, but at least thats a start.  

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[example of your issue](http://jsbin.com/odafog/2/edit#javascript,html,live)

You should close properly your script tags like: `<script src=""></script>`

Comment: Thank you all so much.  That did the trick ... The self-enclosing javascript tags.  Hahaha, gee-wiz.  what a headache over such a silly thing.  :D

Comment: @ArgyleGhost :) no worries! happens to all

Answer (score 0):

When you include the JavaScript files in your page it should look like this:

```
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

If you are going to do it the way you did (not from Google) you have to make sure the `src` path is actually pointing to the JavaScript file.